# Error: can't dereference out of range vector iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration, runtime-error

How can I ensure iterator doesn't go out of range vector? and in the case where the filter would not match any elements of the input; in that case, how can i ensure ensure that begin() is equal to end()
Code

```
 template<typename Iterator>
    struct Range {
        using LazyIterator = Iterator; // required for accessing the used Iterator type from other locations
        Iterator m_begin;
        Iterator m_end;
        auto begin() { return m_begin; }
        auto end() { return m_end; }
    };

struct FilteringIterator : Iterator {
    Callable callable;
    using OriginalIterator = Iterator;
    Iterator end;
    Iterator current=(Iterator &)*this;;
    FilteringIterator(const Iterator begin, Iterator end, Callable callable):Iterator(begin),end(end),callable(callable){}
    Iterator &get_orig_iter() { return ((Iterator &)*this); }
    auto operator++(){ return ((Iterator &)*this)++;}
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const { return ((Iterator &)*this) == rhs; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const { return !(operator==(rhs)); }
    auto operator*() {
        while ((Iterator &)*this!=end && !callable(*get_orig_iter()))
                ++(Iterator &)*this;
        return *(Iterator &)*this;
        }
};

auto filter = [](auto action) {
    return [=]( auto &container) {
        using Container = std::decay_t<decltype(container)>;
        using Iterator = typename Container::iterator;
        using actiontype = decltype(action);
        using filter_iterator = FilteringIterator<Iterator, actiontype>;
        auto t=filter_iterator{container.end(),container.end(),action};
       return Range{filter_iterator{container.begin(),container.end(),action}, filter_iterator{container.end(),container.end(),action}};

    };
};
```

**Main**

```
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        v.push_back(odd_gen() * 2.5);
    // v contains {2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5} here


    for(auto a : v | filter(less_then(15))) // filter is applied lazily as the range is traversed
        std::cout << a <<"D"  << std::endl;
    // prints 17.5 and 22.5 to the console
```

**Output**

```
2.5
7.5
12.5
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Move your while loop to the operator++. Your constructor should also seek the first iterator satisfying your condition.

Comment: You should not use C style cast in C++ code! Use `static_cast` instead. Even better would be to use composition instead. Many of those casts are useless. `OriginalIterator` alias seems useless. Maybe you should consider using a range library (boost, C++ 20...) instead.

Comment: I see what I did wrong, it was such a rookie mistake. moved while loop to `operator!=` with some modification and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move while loop to `operator!=`and return false if begin() is equal to end() to exist for loop